# Select elements in each child tables one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html which is basically a parent table with some child tables inside it,

```
<table id="roottable" class="tablemain" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <table class="intable" align="center" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="chn" colspan="2" align="center">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="mparent">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="ch243" name="ch243" value="243">
                                            <label for="ch243"></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="chtext">Category</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Param two</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="ch244" name="ch244" value="244">
                                        <label for="ch244"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                ......
                ......
                <table class="intable" align="center" border="0">
                ......
                ......
```

What I need to do is access all checkboxes of the nested table, for each table. That is get the checkboxes inside the first nested table, perform some operations with it, move to the next nested table do the same with the checkboxes inside it.

I can access individual tables like below with their id,

```
 $('#tableid').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

});
```

This works, but the tables are auto generated from db and the id is not known beforehand, also, the number of tables may vary, so I have no option other than selecting the parent table and then look for every child tables inside it one by one ... I have tried this ...

```
$('table').each(function(){
 $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    // DO STUFFS WITH CHECKBOXES

});
```

But it doesn't work... How do I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: the latter appears correct, other than failing to separate the `roottable` from the `intable` tables.  Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: The code for each grouping of the tables, are they all the same or different?

Comment: @Huangism They are different. I got it working though. With Kartikeya's solution and then using some conditional statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table tr td').each(function(){  // this line is for main outer table
  $(this).children('table').each(function () {  //this will iterate all the child table
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').each(function(){  //this will find checkbox inside each table
       //Your Stuff
    });
  });
});
```

**NOTE :- I m not using id selector here because questioner mentioned that he doesn't know id's beforehand.**

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rettq2p2/1/)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rettq2p2/2/)

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer

Comment: @Huangism..plz see fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle is good, but that doesn't really provide any explanation on how the code works. It will help the OP and anyone looking at this post in the future

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
var tableInputs = {};
$('#roottable input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    tableInputs[id] = {};
    tableInputs[id][name] = $(this).val();
});
```

This will select all checkboxes that are a child of a table.

**EDIT** if you need to group just find the id of the closest parent table and use that as an index for an object.  You end up with one large object with all the id's as properties, while using only one each loop.

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer

Comment: this will not provide per-table grouping of the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I think using `#roottable` would be better and faster

Comment: @Alnitak that depends on if the code for each grouping of the tables need to be different or not

Comment: The OP says he needs to "move to the next nested table" - that implies grouping.

Comment: @Alnitak it might, but I have a feeling OP does not need grouping since these are generated tables and OP won't know what group is which anyway. He/she only mentioned it because that's the best he/she can explain it, I left a comment asking OP

Comment: It wasn't clear that you needed grouping, just that you needed to go through each table.  I've amended this to allow for grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Your final code block looks acceptable, except that you haven't prevented the `table` selector from also selecting the outer table.  As written, this would cause each set of checkboxes to be considered twice - once as part of its own table and again (actually first) as descendants of the outer table.

Try a more specific selector:

```
$('#roottable .intable').each(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$('#roottable').find('.intable').each(function(index, elt) {
  // operate now on each "child table"
  var $childTable = $(elt);
  $childTable.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, cb){
    // Do your stuff with the checkoxes of the current ".intable" table
  });
});
```